# How do I give a transparent background color for TWebPanel?

Tags: delphi, background, transparency, tms, tms-web-core

As the title states. I want to have a transparent `TWebPanel` component, meaning only the border should be visible.

So I've made a simple form with an image and a panel:

[image]

I want to be able to see the image behind the panel. Here's what I've tried:

- I looked for a transparent property somewhere or any property that might help, but didn't see any.
- I've tried to remove the `Color` property, by making it empty, but that results in an error `'' is not a valid integer value`.
- I looked through the custom colour dialog and there doesn't seem to be an Alpha channel:
  [image]

---

What are my options? How can I make the background of the panel transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. I found out you can assign the `gcNull` or `clNone` value to the `Color` property on the panel. That makes it transparent:

[image: TMS Web Project with image and panel]

Do note though that in design-time, it looks black when the `gcNull` value is assigned to `Color`:

[image: Delphi TWebPanel]

But rest assured that in run-time, it is definitely transparent and not black.

---

And if you want the border to be transparent also, then you can just set the `BorderStyle` property to `bsNone`.